# Spring-MVC using a Converter to load object from path variable, but need to return 404 for unfound

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

TL;DR - Is there a way to throw an error from a registered type converter during the MVC databinding phase such that it will return a response with a specific HTTP status code?  I.e. if my converter can't find an object from the conversion source, can I return a 404?

I have a POJO:

```
public class Goofball {
    private String id = "new";
    // others
    public String getName () { ... }
    public void setName (String name) { ... }
}
```

and am using a StringToGoofballConverter to create an empty object when `"new".equals(id)` or try to load a Goofball from the database if it exists:

```
public Goofball convert(String idOrNew) {
    Goofball result = null;

    log.debug("Trying to convert " + idOrNew + " to Goofball");

    if ("new".equalsIgnoreCase(idOrNew))
    {
        result = new Goofball ();
        result.setId("new");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            result = this.repository.findOne(idOrNew);
        }
        catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            log.error (ex);
        }

        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new GoofballNotFoundException(idOrNew);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

That converter is used by spring when the request matches this endpoint:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/goofballs/{goofball}", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String createOrEditGoofball (@ModelAttribute("goofball") @Valid Goofball object, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    // ... handle the post and save the goofball if there were no binding errors, then return the template string name
}
```

This all works quite well insofar as GET requests to `/admin/goofballs/new` and `/admin/goofballs/1234` work smoothly in the controller for both creating new objects and editing existing ones.  The hitch is that if I issue a request with a bogus id, one that isn't `new` and also doesn't exist in the database I want to return a 404.  Currently the Converter is throwing a custom exception:

```
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason="Goofball Not Found") //404
public class GoofballNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 422445187706673678L;

    public GoofballNotFoundException(String id){
        super("GoofballNotFoundException with id=" + id);
    }
}
```

but I started with a simple IllegalArgumentException as [recommended in the Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator).  In either case, the result is that Spring is returning a response with an HTTP status of 400.

This makes me think I'm misusing the Converter interface but that approach [appears to be recommended by the @ModelAttribute docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args).

So, again the question: is there a way to throw an error from a registered type converter during the databinding phase such that it will return a response with a specific HTTP status code?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

Change `StringToGoofballConverter` to simply return `null` for the unfound entity instead of throwing `IllegalArgumentException` or a custom exception.  The `@Controller` method will then be given a `Goofball` object that has a `null` id (e.g. the id is not "new" nor the path element value).  At that point I can throw a `GoofballNotFoundException` or any other `@ResponseStatus` exception from there, within the controller method to affect the response status code.