# Using MVC type conversion for path variable and returning 404 on null parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My controller. Note the custom `@Exists` annotation:

```
@RestController
public class ClientApiController {

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{client}/someaction", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String handleRequest(@Exists Client client) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

The `Exists` annotation:

```
/**
 * Indicates that a controller request mapping method parametet should not be
 * null. This is meant to be used on model types to indicate a required entity.
 */
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Exists {}
```

The converter which converts the `String` from the path variable into a `Client` instance:

```
@Component
public class StringToClient implements Converter<String, Client> {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDAO clientDAO;

    @Override
    public Client convert(String source) {
        return clientDAO.getClientById(source);
    }
}
```

The `ResourceNotFoundException` exception used to trigger a 404

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

My controller method receives the converted Client as desired. If the `client` id used in the URL matches a client, everything works fine. If the id doesn't match, the `client` parameter is <s>`null`</s> empty (uses default constructor) in the `handle()` controller method.

What I can't get to work now is **declarative** checking that the Client is not null (i.e. that the id refers to an existing client). If it's null, a `ResourceNotFoundException` should be thrown. Checking whether the argument is null in the method body and throwing my custom `ResourceNotFoundException` is easy to do, but repetitive (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254730/spring-mvc-using-a-converter-to-load-object-from-path-variable-but-need-to-retu) one does). Also, this declarative approach should work for all model classes implementing the interface `ModelWithId` so it can be used for multiple model types.

I've searched the Spring documentation and I haven't found how to achieve this. I need to insert some processing somewhere after type conversion and before the controller's `handleRequest` method.

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After type conversion and before the controller's method there is a validation. You can implement custom validator and raise exception in it. Add new validator to `DataBinder`, and mark method's parameter as `@Validated`:

```
@RestController
public class ClientApiController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(DataBinder binder){
        binder.addValidators(new Validator() {
            @Override
            public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
                return aClass==Client.class;
            }

            @Override
            public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {
                Client client = (Client)o;
                if(client.getId()==null) throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
            }
        });
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{client}/someaction", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String handleRequest(@Validated @Exists Client client) {
        // ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/{client}/anotheraction", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    String handleAnotherRequest(@Validated @Exists Client client) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Of course, you can declare validator as separate class, and use it repeatedly in other controllers. Actually, you can raise exception right in your converter, but there is possibility, that you'll need the conversion without exception in other places of your application.

Comment: Indeed validation seems like the proper place to put this. However, how does your solution uses the `@Exists` annotation? I also updated my question a bit because I realized that the client parameter is not `null` but actually an empty instance. It seems you already knew that since the validator you suggest does not check if client is null but only if its id is.

Comment: Unfortunately, Spring's native validation can't access annotation of parameter of controller's method. Validator get parameter as value, and this means that all information about `@Exists` is unavailable. But you can use annotation with JSR-303 (Spring supports it well). Let me know, if you need example, and I'll add my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ken. I chose to use a method call (a `checkExists()` method in in base controller class) instead as there is less "magic" involved that way and I think it's easier to see what's happening. I'll mark your answer as accepted since you provided all the information required to do what I asked. Cheers!

Comment: Less magic means greater control. Wise decision. Was glad to be helpful.