# How can I moderate @PathVariable?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have following methods.

```
public ResponseEntity some(@PathVariable("id") final String id_) {
    final Long id = ((Supplier<Long>) () -> {
        try {
            if (id_ == null || id_.equals("dontcare")) {
                return null;
            }
            return Long.parseLong(id_);
        } catch (final NumberFormatException nfe) {
            throw new RuntimeException(nfe);
        }
    }).get();
}
```

As you can assume I want my parameter value `\d+` or `dontcare`.

How or What can I use for do following?

```
public ResponseEntity some(
    @Dontcare @PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
}
```

I found `WebArgumentHandler`, `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`, and `PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver`, but I can't find any good example.

Please help me.

### UPDATE

I prepared following class.

```
public class DontcarePathVariableResolver
    extends PathVariableMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter parameter) {
        final boolean flag = parameter.getMethodAnnotation(
            DontcarePathVariable.class) != null;
        logger.info("flag: {}", flag);
        return flag;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object resolveName(String name, MethodParameter parameter,
                                 NativeWebRequest request)
            throws Exception {
        @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
        final Map<String, String> templateVariables
                = (Map<String, String>) request.getAttribute(
                HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE,
                RequestAttributes.SCOPE_REQUEST);
        final String pathValue = templateVariables.get(name);
        return new DontcareConverter().convert(pathValue);
    }
}
```

And added it.

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(final List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> resolvers) {
    resolvers.add(new DontcarePathVariableMethodArgumentResolver());
    logger.info("resolver added");
    //super.addArgumentResolvers(resolvers);
}
```

}

But it did come to play.

I think a default handler for `Long` type is already in play.

Comment: @JinKwon is `id` in PathVariable is optional. i.e some time you send data and some time not

Comment: @AjitSoman No the path variable `{id}` is not optional. Client can write on it as digits(e.g. `123`) or literally `dontcare`.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but I think this might get you some of the way to your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35951830/using-mvc-type-conversion-for-path-variable-and-returning-404-on-null-parameter

Comment: @JinKwon . since the `pathvariable` value can be either `String` or `Long` better to set pathVarible data type to `Object` and use `instanceof` operator to check its data type